# Nextcloud AIO - How to persist modifications to php.ini in a docker container that frequently reboots

Tags: php, docker, session, nextcloud, php.ini

I’m running the [Nextcloud AIO docker container](https://github.com/nextcloud/all-in-one). This consists of a master container that then runs the other containers such as the apache, and sql server containers. With this working I want to change it so that after 4 hours of inactivity the user is automatically logged out of the web browser Nextcloud page.

I have found the options I need to change to do this, which can be [found here.](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#user-session)

However an important point to note with the **session_lifetime** option is this:

*The maximum possible time is limited by the session.gc_maxlifetime php.ini setting which would overwrite this option if it is less than the value in the config.php*

By default the **session.gc_maxlifetime** is 1440 seconds which is 24 minutes. I can confirm my session expires after 24 minutes even if set **session_lifetime** to 4 hours.

I have managed to change the **session.gc_maxlifetime** by going into the nextcloud-aio-nextcloud container navigating to **/usr/local/etc/php/** making a copy of the **php.ini-production** or **php.ini-development** and creating a new **php.ini** file. I then delete the **php.ini-development** and **php.ini-production** which leaves me with my newly created **php.ini** file with which I can change the **session.gc_maxlifetime**. With this I can confirm that my desired goal of a timeout after 4 hours of inactivity is achieved. This is the only way I have found to be able to achieve this.

However, every time the containers restart for updates, the changes I made to the **php.ini** are reset. The **php.ini** is gone and has been replaced with the **php.ini-development** and **php.ini-production** again. I have tried to find the corresponding *Dockerfile* in both the nextcloud container and the master container but I can’t find one. I think you can set things in the **Dockerfile** to make changes to a container at boot? I only have a basic understanding of Docker.

I’ve done a lot of research into this but haven't found anything helpful. The only thing mentioned in regards to **session.gc_maxlifetime** [is this](https://github.com/nextcloud/all-in-one/discussions/3673). Where the answer refers to sessions being managed by **redis**. Now there is a running redis container in the nextcloud AIO suite but I have found nothing about session max lifetimes in that container. The answer in that post also points to another issue but that has nothing to do with my problem.

So I’m really not sure how to address this. Ideally I’d want to be able to persist the settings I make to the **php.ini** which includes the creation and deletion of the various **php.ini** files as well as the change to **session.gc_maxlifetime** in **php.ini**. And those settings are kept after the container reboots. All of the other containers are managed, updated and rebooted by the master container which provides a web interface to do so.

I am welcome to other ways of overriding the **session.gc_maxlifetime**.

Comment: Their FAQ says you can edit Nextcloud's `config.php` file from the host like this: `sudo docker run -it --rm --volume nextcloud_aio_nextcloud:/var/www/html:rw alpine sh -c "apk add --no-cache nano && nano /var/www/html/config/config.php"` (update the paths for the config file you need). Note that it's mounting the actual container as readwrite, so the changes stick

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Unless I'm missing something, i've already made the changes to the config.php, but my problem is i can't edit the php.ini file to modify the session.gc_maxlifetime, which is completely separate to any setting in the config.php. session.gc_maxlifetime is php's garbage collection that overrides any session_lifetime setting I set in config.php.